# Android strange ClassCastException

Tags: android, classcastexception

A few days ago we started to receive some crash reports from users using our app, but the stracktrace is really strange. It happens only on Samsung G900f (S5) and I can't reproduce it and decide to post a question here.

The stacktrace shows this:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
   at com.packageName.profile.ProfileFragment.onViewCreated(SourceFile:423)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1086)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1248)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:738)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1613)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(SourceFile:330)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(SourceFile:547)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6258)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

It is a `Fragment` which contains `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with initialization and use all correct, but not sure why this happens.
We got some other `ClassCastExceptions` with different classes from the same device. For example:

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.packageName.model.VideoMeta cannot be cast to 
com.packageName.model.VideoMeta
```

where `VideoMeta` is a class which implements `Parcelable` and this exception occurs in class `Video` which implements `Parcelable` too:

```
private Video(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readLong();
    postId = in.readString();
    url = in.readString();
    thumb = in.readString();
    meta = (VideoMeta) in.readValue(VideoMeta.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

But that's not the end...

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to 
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams
```

I have no idea what can cause this exception and why it's happening, that's why posting it here.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help or suggestions!

Comment: You could use the Samsung [Remote Test Lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/) to test your app on a Galaxy S5, maybe this helps to find the issue.